# Can't check empty editText,while compare variable. Android

Tags: android, compare, android-edittext

```
public OnClickListener submitOcl = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        vibrator.vibrate(30);
        //convert from edittext
        e = editText1.getText().toString();
          e2 = editText2.getText().toString();
         num1 = Integer.parseInt(e);    
         num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2);
          // This is my problem!!!Can't set toast about empty fields
         if(e.length()==0 && e2.length()==0){
             toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Fill all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
                            toast.show(); 
         }
            //if min more than max value output error
         if(num1>num2){
             toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
                            toast.show();
        }
        //output random int value
         else  if (e.length()>0 && e2.length()>0){                   
            int range = num2 - num1 + 1;
            int randomNum =  r.nextInt(range) + num1;                   
            tvResult1.setText(""+randomNum);                
               }             
    }

 };
```

Comment: You're gonna have to clean up your code and be more explicit with your question, or people are going to start yelling.

Comment: *YELLS* *MORE YELLING*

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned:

> // This is my problem!!!Can't set toast about empty fields
>
> if(e.length()==0 && e2.length()==0){

Instead try to check using `isEmpty()`. So if you want to check if both of them are empty then:

```
if(e.isEmpty() && e2.isEmpty()){

}
```

Additional info: If you want to check if your string that is returned from reading the `EditText` is **neither** empty **nor** `null`, then use `if( e!=null && !e.isEmpty()){}`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = Integer.parseInt(e);    
num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2);
```

Those lines will crash your app if the EditText is empty because you can't parse an empty `String` to an `integer`.

I have no idea what your problem is because you didn't tell us, but try this:

```
e = editText1.getText().toString();
e2 = editText2.getText().toString();

try {
     num1 = Integer.parseInt(e);    
     num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2);
}catch (Exception f) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill all fields", 0).show();
}

// you don't need this following code because if an EditText is empty,
// it will be caught in the error and the toast above will execute
// but here is how you could also do it anyways:

/*if(e.isEmpty() && e2.isEmpty()){
    toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill all fields", 
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
    toast.show(); 
}*/
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use [TextUtils.isEmpty](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) while checking a string is null or empty.
Second you may use "or" operator not "and". (As I see from your Toast messages.)

**Edit:** I've edited your code a little.

```
public OnClickListener submitOcl = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        vibrator.vibrate(30);
        // convert from edittext
        e = editText1.getText().toString();
        e2 = editText2.getText().toString();

        // This is my problem!!!Can't set toast about empty fields
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(e) || TextUtils.isEmpty(e2)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();              
        } else {
            try {
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(e);
                num2 = Integer.parseInt(e2);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Only numeric to all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            // if min more than max value output error
            if (num1 > num2) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // output random int value
                int range = num2 - num1 + 1;
                int randomNum = r.nextInt(range) + num1;
                tvResult1.setText("" + randomNum);
            }               
        }
    }
};
```